# Permission Denial: opening provider XXX that is not exported from uid YYY

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity

Разрабатываю приложение на основе [NextGIS Mobile](http://nextgis.ru/nextgis-mobile/). При компиляции исходного кода оригинального приложения оно работает нормально. Если же изменить название пакета, например, на `com.volsu.gis` и собрать приложение, то при попытке открыть начальное активити приложение вылетает со следующей ошибкой:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.volsu.gis, PID: 25621
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.volsu.gis/com.volsu.gis.activity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5624)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                  at com.volsu.gis.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:137)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5624) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
               Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.nextgis.maplib.datasource.LayerContentProvider from ProcessRecord{e33dcdd 25621:com.volsu.gis/u0a132} (pid=25621, uid=10132) that is not exported from uid 10131
                  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
                  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
                  at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3458)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4916)
                  at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2593)
                  at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1491)
                  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:469)
                  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:429)
                  at com.volsu.maplibui.overlay.CurrentTrackOverlay.<init>(CurrentTrackOverlay.java:82)
                  at com.volsu.gis.fragment.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:683)
                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureInflatedFragmentView(FragmentManager.java:1645)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1390)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1640)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1896)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3673)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:338)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:39)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:67)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                  at com.volsu.gis.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:137) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5624) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Глядя на последнюю ошибку, я могу судить только о том, что приложение пытается использовать провайдера со старым именем пакета и потому вылетает.

В манифесте имя пакета указано правильно:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  ~ Project:  NextGIS Mobile
  ~ Purpose:  Mobile GIS for Android.
  ~ Author:   Dmitry Baryshnikov (aka Bishop), bishop.dev@gmail.com
  ~ Author:   NikitaFeodonit, nfeodonit@yandex.com
  ~ Author:   Stanislav Petriakov, becomeglory@gmail.com
  ~ ******************************************************************************
  ~ Copyright (c) 2012-2017 NextGIS, info@nextgis.com
  ~
  ~ This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
  ~ it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
  ~ the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
  ~ (at your option) any later version.
  ~
  ~ This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  ~ but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  ~ MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
  ~ GNU General Public License for more details.
  ~
  ~ You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
  ~ along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
  -->

<manifest package="com.volsu.gis"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
    <!--
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    -->

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="false"/>
    <!--
        <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.camera"
            android:required="false"
            />
        <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.compass"
            android:required="false"
            />
    -->

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

    <application
        android:name="com.volsu.gis.MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name="com.volsu.gis.activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.volsu.gis.activity.IntroActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.volsu.gis.activity.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/action_settings"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.volsu.maplibui.activity.NGWSettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/ngw_accounts"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.volsu.maplibui.activity.NGIDSettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/ngid_settings"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.volsu.gis.activity.AboutActivity"
            android:label="@string/action_help"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.volsu.gis.activity.CreateVectorLayerActivity"
            android:label="@string/create_layer"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

        <service
            android:name="com.volsu.maplibui.account.NGWAuthenticatorService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
                android:resource="@xml/authenticator"/>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name="com.volsu.gis.datasource.SyncService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                    />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                android:resource="@xml/syncadapter"/>
        </service>

        <provider
            android:name="com.volsu.maplib.datasource.LayerContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.volsu.gis.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:syncable="true"/>

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.easypicker.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Код `res/layout/activity_main.xml`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<!--
     As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions.
-->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.volsu.gis.fragment.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_map"/>

    <include
        layout="@layout/actionbar"/>

    <include
        layout="@layout/bottombar"/>
</FrameLayout>

<!--
     android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead.
--><!--
     The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container.
-->

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/layers"
    android:name="com.volsu.gis.fragment.LayersFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_layers"/>
```

Как исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: Полностью как выглядит манифест и какое все таки новое имя пакета?

Comment: @Barmaley, обновил вопрос.

Comment: А что находится в строчке *MainActivity.java:137* - что за лейаут там раскрывается - можно его код тоже привести?

Comment: @Barmaley, `activity_main.xml`

Comment: Беспокоит `com.volsu.gis.fragment.MapFragment` - покажите хотя бы сигнатуру класса `MapFragment`

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась удалением приложения `com.nextgis.mobile`. Так что теперь вопрос заключается в том, как сделать так, чтобы приложения не зависели друг от друга.